# Android: compose item in RecyclerView should overlap nearby items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack-compose, android-custom-view

I have very specific divider which should overlap nearby items with rounded corners:
[image: Divider]

But this divider should overlap nearby items of recyclerView like this:
[image: Divider with vertical offset with lazy column]

I've created the custom layout for this divider and this is how it looks:

```
@Composable
fun Divider() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(6.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .zIndex(1f)
    ) {
        CustomLayout(verticalOffset = 64.dp) {
            DividerWithCorners()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun DividerWithCorners() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier) {
        Row(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Corner(modifier = Modifier.rotate(-90f))
            Corner(modifier = Modifier.rotate(180f))
        }
        Spacer(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(6.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.Black)
        )
        Row(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Corner(modifier = Modifier.rotate(0f))
            Corner(modifier = Modifier.rotate(90f))
        }

    }
}

@Composable
private fun CustomLayout(verticalOffset: Dp, content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    Layout(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(70.dp),
        content = content
    ) { measurables, constraints ->
        val placaebles = measurables.map { measurable ->
            val looseConstraints = constraints.copy(
                minWidth = 0,
                minHeight = 0,
            )
            measurable.measure(
                constraints = looseConstraints.offset(
                    vertical = verticalOffset.roundToPx(),
                )
            )
        }

        layout(
            placaebles.maxOf { it.width },
            placaebles.sumOf { it.height }
        ) {
            placaebles.forEach { placeable ->
                placeable.place(0, 0)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun Corner(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val size = 32.dp
    val bgColor = Color.Black
    Canvas(modifier = modifier.size(size)) {
        drawPath(
            path = Path().apply {
                lineTo(size.toPx(), 0f)
                arcTo(
                    rect = Rect(
                        left = 0f, 
                        top = 0f, 
                        right = 2 * size.toPx(), 
                        bottom = 2 * size.toPx()
                    ), 
                    startAngleDegrees = 270f, 
                    sweepAngleDegrees = -90f, 
                    forceMoveTo = false
                )
                lineTo(0f, size.toPx())
                close()
            }, color = bgColor
        )
    }
}
```

This is not an issue with using LazyColumn as you see. But I need to put this item inside RecyclerView (I use groupie delegate adapter). And this is the result of my attempts with xml RecyclerView:

[image: Missing rounded corners divider]

Looks like this corners just not rendering because they are out of bounds of compose view. Or maybe it is some compose magic with optimisation idk.

I've spend a life trying to solve this issue. Please help me to figure out is it possible and if it is, how should I modify my code.